Definition of innovation in Extended Kalman Filter (EKF)
I was wondering about the definition of the innovation $\mathbf{\alpha}$ defined in EKF (Extended Kalman Filter).
Given the following definitions:

$\mathbf{B}_n = \frac{\partial \mathbf{b}_n (\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$

$\mathbf{y}_n = \mathbf{b}_n (\mathbf{x}_n) + \mathbf{\nu}_n$

$\overline{\mathbf{y}}_n = \mathbf{y}_n - (\mathbf{b}_n (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{n|n-1}) - \mathbf{B}_n \hat{\mathbf{x}}_{n|n-1})$


In the book I am using, it says: $\mathbf{\alpha}_n = \mathbf{y}_n -\mathbf{b}_n (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{n|n-1})$
Shouldn't I be using $\overline{\mathbf{y}}_n$ instead of $\mathbf{y}_n$ in $\mathbf{\alpha}$ definition?

Not every author uses the same notation, so if you're asking a question about a specific text then you should cite the work and provide context for what the author means (like: what is $\alpha$ in this context).  Please edit your question to provide this information.
